# how to change a single value based on properties of another in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to alter the value of a dummy variable for one country for three consecutive years.
I have tries doing the following
Try 1;

```
d[14696, "abort"] = 1
```

Try 2:

```
d$abort <- ifelse(d$drap == 7.826785, 1, d$abort)

d$abort <- ifelse(d$drap == 8.263874, 1, d$abort)

d$abort <- ifelse(d$drap == 12.060453, 1, d$abort)
```

Try 3:

```
d[14698, 6] = 1
```

Try 4:

```
d$abort[14698]  <-  1
```

*the number 14698 is the rownumber

None of them gives any errors which makes me assume they work. However, nothing changes in the data set.. Can someone help?

This is what the data frame looks like for Uruguay which needs to be edited for 2016-2019 on the variable abort:

| Year | Country | Unemp | Poverty | GDPpc | abort | drap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | Uruguay | 8.8379 | 0.2 | 12463 | o | 6.425273 |
| 2013 | Uruguay | 8.3742 | 0.2 | 10849 | 1 | 5.426374 |
| 2014 | Uruguay | 8.1894 | 0.2 | 12938 | 1 | 6.738383 |
| 2015 | Uruguay | 8.2349 | 0.3 | 11823 | 1 | 7.377327 |
| 2016 | Uruguay | 9.2369 | 0.3 | 10828 | o | 7.826785 |
| 2017 | Uruguay | 9.6273 | 0.4 | 10748 | o | 8.263874 |
| 2018 | Uruguay | 8.2374 | 0.3 | 11038 | o | 12.060453 |

Comment: Hello, can you provide us a minimal reproducible example (like a part of your dataframe d) ?

Comment: Picture of a dataframe are not appropriate for different reasons. See here: <https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question>

Comment: Is the column called `Abort` or `abort`? R is case sensitive.

Comment: Using '==' is dangerous because there may be trailing decimal digits that are not displayed by print operations. It's also unclear where the value `14698` comes from. Also unclear why you are trying to change the 6th column in that row when your picture suggests that the "Abort" column is the 3rd.

Answer (score 1):

The below is a tidyverse option based on the assumptions that `drap` is of type double and that `x.` is really `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, Abort = if_else(!is.na(drap), 1, Abort))

## A tibble: 7 x 4
#    Year Country Abort  drap
#    <dbl>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  2012 Uruguay     0 NA   
# 2  2013 Uruguay     1 NA   
# 3  2014 Uruguay     1 NA   
# 4  2015 Uruguay     1 NA   
# 5  2016 Uruguay     1  7.83
# 6  2017 Uruguay     1  8.26
# 7  2018 Uruguay     1 12.1
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018
), Country = c("Uruguay", "Uruguay", "Uruguay", "Uruguay", "Uruguay", 
"Uruguay", "Uruguay"), Abort = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), drap = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 7.826785, 8.263874, 12.060453)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of rjen (while also using his/her dataframe **df** ) I would suggest you might use  dplyr::case_when, such that

```
library(dplyr)


df %>% mutate(Abort = 
                case_when(drap %in% c(7.826785, 8.263874, 12.060453) ~ 1  ## if true
                          ,TRUE ~ Abort) ## if false condition
)
```

Here, if **drap** takes a certain value (similary to your 2nd approach) **Abort** becomes 1. Otherwise **Abort** stays the same. It might be more useful than the regular ifelse condition, as you can connect even more conditions together. You could additionally add something like

```
 case_when(drap %in% c(7.826785, 8.263874, 12.060453) & Year == 2013 ~ 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out through the help of my professor that i had to load my dataset in a different way:

```
d <- d[,c("year", "cname", "wdi_unempilo", "wdi_povgap190", "mad_gdppc", "cai_request", "wdi_homicides")]
```

after that i had to create a new variable for each year, then use this to recode the original variable which was causing issues, and then delete the created variables:

### create new variables

```
d$abort_2016 <- ifelse(d$Country=="Uruguay" & d$Year==2016,  1, d$abort)

d$abort_2017 <- ifelse(d$Country=="Uruguay" & d$Year==2017,  1, d$abort)

d$abort_2018 <- ifelse(d$Country=="Uruguay" & d$Year==2018,  1, d$abort)
```

### use created variables to recode

```
d$abort <- ifelse(d$abort_2016 == 1, 1, d$abort)

d$abort <- ifelse(d$abort_2017 == 1, 1, d$abort)

d$abort <- ifelse(d$abort_2018 == 1, 1, d$abort)
```

### Subset to remove created variables

```
d <-  subset(d, select = -c(abort_2016,abort_2016) )

d <-  subset(d, select = -c(abort_2017,abort_2017) )

d <-  subset(d, select = -c(abort_2018,abort_2018) )
```

This solved my issue